# How do I redirect or refresh an aspx page after exporting of an excel file?

Tags: asp.net

After I click on the export button I am able to export the excel file, I want to redirect the page after response has been written to client i.e after response.flush(). can I do that?

Comment: redirection work as usual .Like Response.Redirect("URL").

Comment: if you redirect after flushing, you will lose the file

Comment: @m.kudi &Ted - thank u, but I want to refresh the page, and as Ted said I am losing a file if I use response.redirect() before response.flush()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting a page after a PDF download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288941/redirecting-a-page-after-a-pdf-download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reload/redirect in code behind and export a file at the same time.
It's better to use javascript. Add a `OnClientClick` to the export button and wait for x milliseconds before reloading.

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="sleepAfterClick()" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sleepAfterClick() {
            setTimeout(function () { location.href = "http://www.google.nl" }, 2000);
        }
    </script>
```

If you set the timeout for too short a time, it will reload the page and the exort will not happen. So make sure it is always a safe amount of time longer than it takes to create the Excel.