# Redirecting to another page after a PDF download

Tags: c#

I have an aspx (say 1.aspx) page from where first I am downloading a pdf file and then I want to redirect to some 2.aspx page. The code is this:

```
protected void buttSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Submit button to generate PDF
    {            
            if (intInvoID > 0)
            {
               UpdateInvoice();          
            }
            else
            {
                SaveInvoice();      
            }

            GenearatePDf(strheader, htrFooter, strContact, strExihibition, strPaymentDetails, strNotes);
            Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "12;URL=~/expo_crm/invoice/View_Invoices.aspx");

        }
    }
```

Here,I am not able to redirect to View_Invoices.aspx. I tried using Response.header.But its not working.

```
private void GenearatePDf(string strheader, string strFooter, string strContact, string strExihibition, string strPaymentDetails, string strNotes)
    {
             Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice_" + txtCompanyName.Text.Trim() + ".pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            StringReader srHtmlText = new StringReader(sbHtmlText.ToString());
            Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 40f, 40f, 15f, 2f);

            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker htmlparser = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(pdfDocument);

            PdfWriter pdfDoc1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream);
            var page = new ITextEvents();
            page.email = txtExpogrEmail.Text.Trim();
            pdfDoc1.PageEvent = page;



            pdfDocument.Open();
            pdfDocument.Add(ph1);
            pdfDocument.Add(tblBlank);
            pdfDocument.Add(tblAddInfo);

            pdfDocument.Add(tblCon);
            pdfDocument.Add(tblExhibition);
            pdfDocument.Add(tblNotes);
            pdfDocument.Add(iHeader);

            pdfDocument.Add(jpg);
            pdfDocument.Add(jpg1);

            htmlparser.Parse(srHtmlText);
            pdfDocument.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDocument);
            //Response.End();}
```

Comment: Have you tried Response.Redirect ?

Comment: yes...its not working

Comment: Why don't you show us what you tried?

Comment: I would suggest redirecting to page 2 first, passing a parameter to signify the PDF download, then download the pdf file once on page 2.

Comment: my page 2 is about viewing the invoice.My pdf is gettting generated but after generating pdf it should go to viewinvoice.aspx page.So i have added Response.header(--).But its not working.i tried using breakpoint.it goes to till generatePdf mtd and henerating pdf and does not go to Response.header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288941/redirecting-a-page-after-a-pdf-download

Comment: yes aria..i tried using reponse.addheader but it dint worked.

Comment: Let us see `GenearatePDf` code.

Comment: GenearatePDf(strheader, htrFooter, strContact, strExihibition, strPaymentDetails, strNotes);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------          
            Response.Redirect("~/expo_crm/invoice/View_Invoices.aspx");
            Response.End();--------------i slightly modify the code...here it is redirecting to a page2.aspx but not generating the pdf.

Comment: @Aria....I have just added the code that generates pdf

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the `Refresh` header only works when you're serving a HTML document. Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header), it is equivalent to the `<meta http-equiv="refresh" url="..." />` head tag. Which can only appear in an html document.