# How to make 2 process in return using C# Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, text-files, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a download process that after it gets the record and write it to a text file it opens a SaveFileDialog to allow users to save wherever they want. The process is working fine but after it download the file you need to refresh the page to take effect and removes the rows downloaded.

And one more thing when I use google chrome it download the file automatically but when using brave browser it opens a SaveFileDialog. below is my code in downloading the file.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadList()
{
  [some codes/process here]...

  // lets the user save the file where they want to the save the file.
  var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\files\\", "file.txt");
  return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file), "application/octet-stream", "file.txt"); 
}
```

is there a way to add `RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));` in the return line?

Comment: Similar question with answers that might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289195/1398417
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289040/1398417