# Completed event fire after file download in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to do notified on the server when a client browser requests to download a file, and the file finishes downloading, can I have execute completed event when file download is complete or canceled by user.

When the users browser will request to save the file (or just download it), When the download completes I want the web server to then delete the file.

I have been looking at `IHTTPModule` and the `EndRequest` event, But this doesn't appear to be any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Comment: a solution for this is offered in the highlighted anwser [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666468/detecting-when-the-file-download-popup-is-closed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4168965/105445

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for  OnResultExecuted method.

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
           // implement your code here
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
```