# S3: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for AJAX POST

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, cors, jquery-file-upload

This issue is driving me a little nuts.  I'm trying to upload files via AJAX POST to an S3 bucket.

I have all the credentials correct because when I do normal HTTP POSTs it creates the resource in the S3 bucket just fine.  But I would really like to upload multiple file at once with progress bars, hence I need AJAX.

I have CORS setup on my S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Right now I'm just trying to get it working in my development environment (localhost:3000, using standard Rails 4.1).

From my understanding, the above CORS rule should allow AJAX requests from localhost:3000 to the S3 bucket.

However, every time I submit a file via AJAX, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because localhost:3000 IS granted access via the CORS rule.

I've also provided a snippet of the JS I used to submit the form:

```
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET>",
    data: $(this).serialize() # Contains S3 necessary values
  })
```

The form has inputs for the Amazon S3 keys/etc necessary.  I know they work because when I do normal HTTP POSTs it creates the asset properly in S3.  All I'm trying to do is AJAXify the process.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Using: Rails 4.1, jquery-file-upload, fog gem (for S3)

Comment: Have you verified that the `POST` is sending a `Origin` header? It seems likely that some browsers may not because they treat `localhost` as a different security level.

Comment: I checked that out already. I'm using Chome's Developer Tools and it says it's submitting an `Origin: http://localhost:3000` in the request. It does have a note saying `CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown`.  I haven't looked that up yet but I guess I need to rule that out as well.

Comment: @klchoi: It's been a year since I touched this issue, but I believe Amazon pushed out some updates that resolved my issue by allowing direct POSTing to their buckets.  I'm not on that project anymore so I can't verify.  Sorry I can't provide more insight.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by changing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems very similar to a problem I had, which was never properly (precisely) answered either and seemed to be an issue related to a browser limitation instead of the actual transfer technology behind it.

Here's a link to my original question and the answers I received here on SO:
[Why Doesn't Microsoft Skydrive Download Multiple Files via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913274/why-doesnt-microsoft-skydrive-download-multiple-files-even-though-ms-example-sh)

Hopefully this may offer some insight into your problem and isn't just noise.