# Is it possible to disable a Button until download is finished?

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to solve the following problem, but I can't come up with an appropriate solution:

> Disabling a button (with an underlying Download link) when the download starts (button has clicked once) and enable the button again when the download is completed?

I tried to Google it but couldn't even find a helpful hint. Is this even possible in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 possible options that you might want to look at.

1. This link might be useful to you as a place to get started from:

   http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/

   The idea is to use a cookie to define when the file is downloaded. In theory you could write your JavaScript to detect the cookie and then re-enable the button. A good outline for detecting a cookie in JavaScript can be found here: [What is the shortest function for reading a cookie by name in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639346/shortest-function-for-reading-a-cookie-in-javascript)
2. Another solution might be to have a look at this question: 
   [detecting when the "File download" popup is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666468/detecting-when-the-file-download-popup-is-closed)

   While it's not exactly what you're looking for - the answer by Crescent Fresh could probably be adapted so that for the period of the download your button is disabled.
3. Or a quick but inelegant solution would be to disable the download button for somewhere between 30 seconds and 2 minutes to prevent users clicking the button again immediately while the file downloads - it's the least work, but it doesn't account for different download speeds etc.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Hollie3406! Your answer helped me to get on the right path.

Comment: Even though the first link looks old, this is still a very good (and easy) way of implementing this feature. It took around 15 minutes and works perfectly. 

A few hints to make it even easier:

1) Use js-cookie library, which has replaced the jQuery library (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/latest#readme)

2) From server-side, simply call:
HttpContext.Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", model.FileDownloadToken));

Before returning regular FileContentResult, i.e.:
return File(file.Data, mimeType, file.FileName);